# I want to use required attribute

Tags: html, forms

why i cant use `required`  attrib in my select option

```html
<form>
<select required="" name="Furniture" id="Furniture" class="form-control input-lg"  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Furniture</option>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you mean? Where is your `button` or `input` type="submit"`?

Comment: my required attribute seems not working

Comment: here `<input type="button" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung()" class="myButton">`

Comment: `<select required="" name="Furniture" id="Furniture" class="form-control input-lg"  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Furniture</option>
    <option value="kitchen">Kitchen Set</option>
    <option value="meja">Meja Bar</option>
   </select>`

Comment: Please update your question with HTML/JS. Don't provide the code in  comments.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain your full code.

Comment: @SamuelAsor Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try using the required attribute without the `=""`, as below:

```
<select required>
  <option value="">Select Furniture</option>
</select>
```

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out
>   before submitting the form.

Comment: I don't think this was the issue... The OP was using `input type="button"` instead of `input type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

Required is a boolean attribute. If that attribute is present, it means that the value of required attribute is true, else it's false. it If you are using HTML5, just write required without equal to double quotes.
Try this :

```
<form>
<select required name="Furniture" id="Furniture" class="form-control input-lg"  >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Furniture</option>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think this was the issue... The OP was using `input type="button"` instead of `input type="submit"`.